# Reinstalling Windows for ssd+hdd cache

Tags: windows-7, ssd, hard-drive-cache

I currently have windows installed on a small SSD with a TB HDD being used as a data volume.  I want to use Intel's Smart Response Technology to allow the SSD to be used as a cache.

Before I go ahead and do this, can you tell me if this will cause problems with Windows activation when I change over to the RAID configuration and reinstall windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not. I have done the exact same thing without any issues. Make sure you have your CD key before attempting. Please do a standard reformat/install. SRT is fairly painless, just follow Intel's instructions on how to do it.